# Degree of a polynomial as smooth map - clarification

Tags: polynomials, differential-topology

I would like to a clarification of the [following question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456248/degree-of-p-as-a-smooth-function-equals-its-polynomial-degree-d) I cannot understand the last three lines, where we conclude that the exponents $n_1=n_2=...n_k=1$, which then concludes our proof. Cannot understand why the condition of the jacobian implies the one on the $n_s$. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the derivative of the polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $q$ is a regular value, then the derivative of the polynomial at every root is different from $0$.

Note that the only possibility to have the derivative different from $0$ at every $x_j$ for all $j=1,...,k$ is that $n_1=...=n_k=1$, since in this case the derivative does not equal $0$.

By the condition that the sum of all the $n$'s is equal to $d$, you easily get the result recalling that for holomorphic proper functions $deg(F)=\#F^{-1}(q)$.